# Proving that set $U$ is subspace of space $V$

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $V=\mathbb{R}^4$ be a space. Prove or disprove:
$$
U=Span\left\{ \begin{bmatrix}-1\\ 2\\ 0\\ 9 \end{bmatrix},\begin{bmatrix}3\\ 5\\ -8\\ 2 \end{bmatrix},\begin{bmatrix}2\\ 0\\ -4\\ 11 \end{bmatrix}\right\}
$$

is a subspace of $V$.
Usually when I have to prove that $U$ is subspace of $V$ I show that:

1. $U$ is not empty.
2. for every $u,v\in U$ we get $u+v\in U$.
3. for every $u\in U$ and $\lambda\in \mathbb{F}$ we get $\lambda u\in U$.

But due to span, I'm not sure how to show it. Of course  $U$ is not empty. What about the other two?

Comment: Hint: take an $x\in V$. Can you show that you can write $x$ as a linear combination of things in $U$?

Comment: How are you defining "Span"?

Answer (score 1):

As you pointed out, it is easy to see that $U$ is nonempty. It is also a subset of $\mathbb{R}^4$.

Let $u, v\in U$ and $a = \begin{bmatrix}-1\\ 2\\ 0\\ 9 \end{bmatrix}, b= \begin{bmatrix}3\\ 5\\ -8\\ 2 \end{bmatrix},$ and $c = \begin{bmatrix}2\\ 0\\ -4\\ 11 \end{bmatrix}$. Then $u = \lambda_1a+\lambda_2b+\lambda_3c$ and $v = \lambda_4a+\lambda_5b+\lambda_6c$ for some scalars $\lambda_1,\lambda_2,\lambda_3,...,\lambda_6$. Since $u + v = (\lambda_1+\lambda_4)a+(\lambda_2+\lambda_5)b+(\lambda_3+\lambda_6)c, u+v\in\mathrm{Span}\{a,b,c\}\Rightarrow u+v\in U.$

Now let $u\in U$ and $\lambda\in \mathbb{R}$. Then $\lambda u=(\lambda\lambda_1)a+(\lambda\lambda_2)b+(\lambda\lambda_3)c$ so $\lambda u\in U$.

Hence $U$ is a subspace of $\mathbb{R}^4$.